# Redirect to php page after insert data in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I want to redirect my form to a php page after submit and after data of the form have been inserted (in a correct way) in my database.
I use action="insert-data.php" to insert data but I want to redirect the user to a different php page (that is not a welcome page). How can i redirect him after the insert?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: look in the manual for the header() function

Comment: Ok, so adding the header I use the insert-data.php to insert data but i'm being redirected to another page, isn't it?

Comment: But Have I to use insert-data.php (where I would insert my header)  as external page or can I call the action in the same page of the form? @Dagon, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use `header("Location: http://example.com/page.html");`
but make sure you don´t print or echo anything, no output at all before that call.

Comment: that should be the full URI, not a relative one

Comment: wasn´t sure about that, i´ll check ;)